# Extract text from a jpg table with no lines in Python

Tags: python, text, jpeg

I am new to Python and I am trying to extract the tabular data from a jpeg, where there are no lines in the table. I've tried using pytesseract but I only get one column of data in the output.

Here is a screen shot of the type of table I want to extract the data from.
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAGOM.jpg)

Any helpful advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code you mentioned that you've tried?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. 

Yes its simply:

pip install pytesseract

import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(r'D:\02_Scripts\jupyter\test.jpg'))

Comment: Using this sample jpg the output format is strange as it misses off the Region column. In the original jpg table that I have I only have an output where there are no regions and also the columns are all merged so there is just a single column of data. Thanks for your help

Comment: Could someone let me know how I can add my example code in a more readable format? Thanks!!